# Is this correct: $\ln({(-1)}^{2x-1})=(2x-1)\ln(-1)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I would expect the answer to be positive, but it appears otherwise for some values of $x \geq 1$.

Here is a simple C++ code that I have used in order to test this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

void test(double x)
{
    complex<double> i(0,1);
    complex<double> res1 = (2*x-1)*log(i*i);
    complex<double> res2 = log(pow(i*i,2*x-1));
    cout<<res1<<endl;
    cout<<res2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not true in general, since $-1$ is negative. Wolfram Alpha only finds $0.8$ as a solution.

Comment: Which logarithm (there are infinitely many) of $(-1)^{2x-1}$ and $-1$ are you using?

Comment: $\ln(-1)$ is usually left undefined, unless $\ln$ is defined as a a multi-valued function.

Comment: In particular, computational packages like those found on C++ are not going to really be useful to figuring out what is happening with the natural log function.

Comment: @Oliver: It should be correct according to logarithm rules. Why is it (mathematically) wrong then?

Comment: @mrf: The question states $ln$, which is the natural logarithm (and in any case, according to logarithm rules, it should also hold for any other logarithm).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks. I believe that $ln(-1)$ is well defined for complex number (which is one of the tags on this question, by the way). Am I wrong?

Comment: @barakmanos you're missing the point. Of course it's the natural logarithm, but in order to plug in negative numbers, you need the complex version which is not uniquely determined.

Comment: Thanks @mrf. I suspected that's what you meant; will have a look into it (unless you can briefly describe what exactly it means).